# Locate first and last non NaN values in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a Pandas `DataFrame` indexed by date. There a number of columns but many columns are only populated for part of the time series. I'd like to find where the first and last values non-`NaN` values are located so that I can extracts the dates and see how long the time series is for a particular column.

Could somebody point me in the right direction as to how I could go about doing something like this?

Comment: [first_valid_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html#pandas.Series.first_valid_index) and [last_valid_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html#pandas.Series.last_valid_index)

Comment: Is there a solution for this when the missing values can be "0"? (i.e find the first non zero value, per group/time series)?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

@behzad.nouri's solution worked perfectly to return the first and last non-`NaN values` using [Series.first_valid_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html#pandas.Series.first_valid_index) and [Series.last_valid_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html#pandas.Series.last_valid_index), respectively.

Comment: @KorayTugay A pandas Series is 1D (i.e. single column). If you want to check more columns in a `df` you can iterate over your df. Eg. `for col_name, data in df.items():
    print("First valid index for column {} is at {}".format(col_name, data.first_valid_index()))`

Comment: Instead of iterating over the columns of a DataFrame, you can use `df.apply(Series.first_valid_index)`.

Answer (score 56):

Here's some helpful examples.

#### Series

```
s = pd.Series([np.NaN, 1, np.NaN, 3, np.NaN], index=list('abcde'))
s

a    NaN
b    1.0
c    NaN
d    3.0
e    NaN
dtype: float64

# first valid index
s.first_valid_index()
# 'b'

# first valid position
s.index.get_loc(s.first_valid_index())
# 1

# last valid index
s.last_valid_index()
# 'd'

# last valid position
s.index.get_loc(s.last_valid_index())
# 3
```

Alternative solution using `notna` and `idxmax`:

```
# first valid index
s.notna().idxmax()
# 'b'

# last valid index
s.notna()[::-1].idxmax()
# 'd'
```

---

#### DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [np.NaN, 1, np.NaN, 3, np.NaN], 
    'B': [1, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]
})
df

     A    B
0  NaN  1.0
1  1.0  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
3  3.0  NaN
4  NaN  NaN
```

`(first|last)_valid_index` isn't defined on DataFrames, but you can apply them on each column using `apply`.

```
# first valid index for each column
df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index)

A    1
B    0
dtype: int64

# last valid index for each column
df.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index)

A    3
B    0
dtype: int64
```

As before, you can also use `notna` and `idxmax`. This is slightly more natural syntax.

```
# first valid index
df.notna().idxmax()

A    1
B    0
dtype: int64

# last valid index
df.notna()[::-1].idxmax()

A    3
B    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: The issue with `idxmax()` is that it will return `0` for a full-`NaN` column. I would expect a `NaN` in that case, so I would rather always use `.apply(Series.first_valid_index)`.

Comment: For the whole dataframe you can find the first index that has no NaNs with `df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index).max()`

Comment: For everyone who came here because of the same question in `xarray` (like me): The “alternative solution” works, but the functions are called differently in `xarray`. Use `da.notnull().idxmax(dim_name)` to get the first valid position, where `da` is a `DataArray` and `dim_name` the name of the dimension along which to search for `NaN` values. For the last valid position, add `.isel(dim=slice(None, None, -1))`.

Answer (score 1):

A convenience function based on **behzad.nouri**'s commend and **cs95**'s earlier answer. Any errors or misunderstandings are mine.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([["2022-01-01", np.nan, np.nan, 1], ["2022-01-02", 2, np.nan, 2], ["2022-01-03", 3, 3, 3], ["2022-01-04", 4, 4, 4], ["2022-01-05", np.nan, 5, 5]], columns=['date', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df
#        date    A    B    C
#0 2022-01-01  NaN  NaN  1.0
#1 2022-01-02  2.0  NaN  2.0
#2 2022-01-03  3.0  3.0  3.0
#3 2022-01-04  4.0  4.0  4.0
#4 2022-01-05  NaN  5.0  5.0
```

We want to start at the earliest date common to A and B and end at the latest date common to A and B (for whatever reason, we do not filter by column C).

```
# filter data to minimum/maximum common available dates
def get_date_range(df, cols):
    """return a tuple of the earliest and latest valid data for all columns in the list"""
    a,b = df[cols].apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index).max(), df[cols].apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index).min()
    return (df.loc[a, 'date'], df.loc[b, 'date'])

a,b = get_date_range(df, cols=['A', 'B'])
a
#Timestamp('2022-01-03 00:00:00')
b
#Timestamp('2022-01-04 00:00:00')
```

Now filter the data:

```
df.loc[(df.date >= a) & (df.date <= b)]
#        date    A    B    C
#2 2022-01-03  3.0  3.0  3
#3 2022-01-04  4.0  4.0  4
```