# Pandas - find first non-null value in column

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a series that has either NULL or some non-null value.  How can I find the 1st row where the value is not NULL so I can report back the datatype to the user.  If the value is non-null all values are the same datatype in that series.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309514/computing-the-first-non-missing-value-from-each-column-in-a-dataframe

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) with select by `loc`:

```
s = pd.Series([np.nan,2,np.nan])
print (s)
0    NaN
1    2.0
2    NaN
dtype: float64

print (s.first_valid_index())
1

print (s.loc[s.first_valid_index()])
2.0

# If your Series contains ALL NaNs, you'll need to check as follows:

s = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])
idx = s.first_valid_index()  # Will return None
first_valid_value = s.loc[idx] if idx is not None else None
print(first_valid_value)
None
```

Comment: If the series contains duplicate index values `s.loc[idx]` would actually return a series. @jezrael do you think there's a good general solution that will also work in that case or is conditioning on the type of `first_valid_value` inevitable?

Comment: @Stav - Not easy question, maybe the best post new question.

Comment: @jezrael For the last valid value, would you just reverse the series and use the same fn?

Comment: @jtlz2 - use `last_valid_index`

Answer (score 15):

For a series this will return the first no null value:

Creating Series s:

```
s = pd.Series(index=[2,4,5,6], data=[None, None, 2, None])
```

which creates this Series:

```
2    NaN
4    NaN
5    2.0
6    NaN
dtype: float64
```

You can get the first non-NaN value by using:

```
s.loc[~s.isnull()].iloc[0]
```

which returns

```
2.0
```

If you on the other hand have  a dataframe like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[2,4,5,6], data=np.asarray([[None, None, 2, None], [1, None, 3, 4]]).transpose(), 
                  columns=['a', 'b'])
```

which looks like this:

```
    a       b
2   None    1
4   None    None
5   2       3
6   None    4
```

you can select per column the first non null value using this (for column a):

```
df.a.loc[~df.a.isnull()].iloc[0]
```

or if you want the first row containing no Null values anywhere you can use:

```
df.loc[~df.isnull().sum(1).astype(bool)].iloc[0]
```

Which returns:

```
a    2
b    3
Name: 5, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `get` method instead

```
(Pdb) type(audio_col)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
(Pdb) audio_col.first_valid_index()
19
(Pdb) audio_col.get(first_audio_idx)
'first-not-nan-value.ogg'
```