# Find closest valid numbers among missing values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataset with multiple missing sequences of varying lengths where I'd like to find the  first valid numbers that occur **before and after** these sequences for some particular dates. In the sample dataset below, I would like to find the valid numbers for `ColumnB` that occur closest to the date  `2018-11-26`.

**Datasample:**

```
Date         ColumnA   ColumnB
2018-11-19   107.00      NaN
2018-11-20   104.00      NaN
2018-11-21   106.00      NaN
2018-11-22   105.24    80.00
2018-11-23   104.63      NaN
2018-11-26   104.62      NaN
2018-11-28   104.54      NaN
2018-11-29   103.91    86.88
2018-11-30   103.43      NaN
2018-12-01   106.13      NaN
2018-12-02   110.83      NaN
```

**Expected output:**

```
[80, 86.88]
```

**Some details:**

If it were the case that this particular sequence was the only one with missing values, I would have been able to solve it using `For Loops`, or the pandas functions `first_valid_index()` or `isnull()` as described in [Pandas - find first non-null value in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137529/pandas-find-first-non-null-value-in-column), but that will rarely be the case.

I'm able to solve this using a few `For Loops`, but it's very slow for larger datasets and not very elegant, so I'd really like to hear other suggestions!

Comment: The close to 2018-11-16 is 80.00 why do you get a second value?  Oh.  I think you ment 2018-11-26?

Comment: @ScottBoston You're absolutely right! I've edited the question.

Comment: If you want to find the *closest* non-null number, based on the `Date` then this is really just an interpolation problem: `df.set_index('Date').ColumnB.interpolate('nearest').ffill().bfill()`. If it's interpolation just based on index, then no need to `.set_index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way, get the index and slice to get the first valid number

```
idx= np.where(df['Date']=='2018-11-26')[0][0]
# idx 3

num = (df.loc[df.loc[:idx,'ColumnB'].first_valid_index(),'ColumnB'],
       df.loc[df.loc[idx:,'ColumnB'].first_valid_index(),'ColumnB'])

num
(80.0, 86.879999999999995)
```

Comment: @ScottBoston Hope thats better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ffill` and `bfill` to create two columns with the value from before and after such as

```
df['before'] = df.ColumnB.ffill()
df['after'] = df.ColumnB.bfill()
```

then get the value for the dates you want with a `loc`

```
print (df.loc[df.Date == pd.to_datetime('2018-11-26'),['before','after']].values[0].tolist())
[80.0, 86.88]
```

and if you have a list of dates then you can use `isin`:

```
list_dates = ['2018-11-26','2018-11-28']
print (df.loc[df.Date.isin(pd.to_datetime(list_dates)),['before','after']].values.tolist())
[[80.0, 86.88], [80.0, 86.88]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd try it this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_vld = df.dropna()

idx = np.argmin(abs(df_vld.index - pd.datetime(2018, 11,26)))
# 1

df_vld.loc[df_vld.index[idx]]
Out:
ColumnA    103.91
ColumnB     86.88
Name: 2018-11-29 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[df['ColumnB'].ffill().loc['2018-11-26'], df['ColumnB'].bfill().loc['2018-11-26']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it:

```
t = '2018-11-26'
```

Look for the index of the date `t`:

```
ix = df.loc[df.Date==t].index.values[0]
```

Keep positions of non-null values in `ColumnB`:

```
non_nulls = np.where(~df.ColumnB.isnull())[0]
```

Get the nearest non-null values both on top and bellow:

```
[df.loc[non_nulls[non_nulls < ix][-1],'ColumnB']] + [df.loc[non_nulls[non_nulls > ix][0],'ColumnB']]

[80.0, 86.88]
```