# ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, typeerror

I have a `df` where a particular col has several null values. I want to extract the first non null value.

```
print(df.kst_erloes_stpfl.to_list())
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 'WH042700', 90510000, 90510000]
```

```
import numpy as np

def not_na(array):
    return ~np.isnan(array)

def first_not_na_value(array):
    return list(filter(not_na, array))[0]

first = first_not_na_value(df.kst_erloes_stpfl)
print(first)
```

However, I get this error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

What else can I try to extract the first non null value?

Comment: use `df.kst_erloes_stpfl.notnull()`.

Comment: how would I extract the first value from this then? If I print the result of this, I just get true or false @QuangHoang

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42137562/13145954) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use pandas built-in function dropna:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

values = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
          np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'WH042700', 90510000, 90510000]

df = pd.DataFrame(values)

first_non_na = df.dropna().iloc[0,0]

print(first_non_na)
```