# what is replacement for any() method in dataframes in latest versions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have the need of using any() method of the data frame. This used to return the first non-empty value in the series but now it returns only true/false value.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{"a":"asdfads10", "b":100}, {"a":"10asdfasdf","b":200}])
>>> df['a'].any()
True
```

Can you help if you have seen any alternative?

Comment: Do you want the first row where `a` is not null?

Comment: Maybe this is what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137529/pandas-find-first-non-null-value-in-column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - find first non-null value in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137529/pandas-find-first-non-null-value-in-column)