# Python "Most Recent Value Backfill" Is Slow

Tags: python, r, pandas, data.table

I currently have an R-based algorithm that sorts a data.table by date and then finds the most recent non-NA / non-null value. I've found some success with the following 
 StackOverflow question to implement a backfilling algorithm for some relatively large datasets:

[Computing the first non-missing value from each column in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309514/computing-the-first-non-missing-value-from-each-column-in-a-dataframe)

I've implemented a solution both in Python and in R, but my Python solution seems to be running much, much slower.

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

test_values <- rnorm(100000)
test_values[sample(1:length(test_values), size = 10000)] <- NA

test_values_2 <- rnorm(100000)
test_values_2[sample(1:length(test_values), size = 10000)] <- NA

test_ids <- rpois(100000, lambda = 100)
random_timestamp <- sample(x = seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), as.Date('2017-01-01'), by = 1), size = 100000, replace = TRUE)
dt <- data.table(
    'id' = test_ids,
    'date' = random_timestamp,
    'v1' = test_values,
    'v2' = test_values_2
)


# Simple functions for backfilling
backfillFunction <- function(vector) {
    # find the vector class
    colClass <- class(vector)
    if (all(is.na(vector))) {
        # return the NA of the same class as the vector
        NA_val <- NA
        class(NA_val) <- colClass
        return(NA_val)
    } else {
        # return the first non-NA value
        return(vector[min(which(!is.na(vector)))])
    }
}

print(microbenchmark(
    dt[order(-random_timestamp), lapply(.SD, backfillFunction), by = 'id', .SDcols = c('v1', 'v2')]
))

Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                                              expr      min       lq
 dt[order(-random_timestamp), c(lapply(.SD, backfillFunction),      list(.N)), by = "id", .SDcols = c("v1", "v2")] 9.976708 12.29137
    mean   median       uq      max neval
 15.4554 14.47858 16.75997 112.9467   100
```

And the Python solution:

```
import timeit

setup_statement = """
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1)
step = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
current_date = start_date

dates = []
while current_date < end_date:
    dates.append(current_date)
    current_date += step

date_vect = np.random.choice(dates, size=100000, replace=True)
test_values = np.random.normal(size=100000)
test_values_2 = np.random.normal(size=100000)
na_loc = [np.random.randint(0, 100000, size=10000)]
na_loc_2 = [np.random.randint(0, 100000, size=10000)]
id_vector = np.random.poisson(100, size=100000)

for i in na_loc:
    test_values[i] = None

for i in na_loc_2:
    test_values_2[i] = None


DT = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'id': id_vector,
        'date': date_vect,
        'v1': test_values,
        'v2': test_values_2
    }
)
GT = DT.sort_values(['id', 'date'], ascending=[1, 0]).groupby('id')
"""

print(timeit.timeit('{col: GT[col].apply(lambda series: series[series.first_valid_index()] if series.first_valid_index() else None) for col in DT.columns}', number=100, setup=setup_statement)*1000/100)


66.5085821699904
```

My average time on Python is 67ms, but for R it is only 15, even though the approach seems relatively similar (apply a function over each column within groups). Why is my R code so much quicker than my Python code, and how can I achieve similar performance in Python?

Comment: Profile your code.

Comment: Can you avoid calling `series.first_valid_index()` twice?

Comment: @Roland Noted on the profiling - I had done that on the Python code but wasn't really sure how to speed up the slow parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to add another perhaps clearer answer. Define a function that gets the first non-missing value unless they are all missing then returns null.

```
def find_first(s):
    s = s.dropna()
    if len(s) == 0:
        return np.nan
    return s.iloc[0]

GT = DT.sort_values(['id', 'date'], ascending=[True, False])
GT.groupby(['id']).agg(find_first).reset_index()
```

Also done with

```
GT.set_index('id').stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).first().unstack()
```

#### Original Answer

Stacking the values will automatically remove missing values and put them all in one column. Then you can just take the first row. There are a lot of steps here but most of them are just reshaping to make it look correct.

```
DT.sort_values(['id', 'date'], ascending=[True, False])\
  .set_index(['date', 'id'])\
  .stack()\
  .reset_index()\
  .groupby(['id', 'level_2'])\
  .first()\
  .set_index('date', append=True)\
  .squeeze()\
  .unstack('level_2')\
  .reset_index()\
  .rename_axis(None, axis='columns')
```

Output

```
     id       date        v1        v2
0     53 2015-08-29       NaN  1.700798
1     59 2000-04-25 -0.560505  0.371487
2     60 2011-01-07       NaN  0.627205
3     61 2001-03-13       NaN  0.245077
4     61 2011-01-11  0.992256       NaN
5     62 2005-04-14 -0.541771 -1.559377
6     63 2016-03-25  0.338544  0.176700
7     64 2016-07-12 -0.297969 -0.977407
8     65 2009-04-24       NaN -0.429607
9     65 2009-05-04  1.829951       NaN
```

Extra: You can vastly improve the building of your dataframe like this

```
dates = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', '2017-1-1')

date_vect = np.random.choice(dates, size=100000, replace=True)
test_values = np.random.normal(size=100000)
test_values_2 = np.random.normal(size=100000)
na_loc = [np.random.randint(0, 100000, size=10000)]
na_loc_2 = [np.random.randint(0, 100000, size=10000)]
id_vector = np.random.poisson(100, size=100000)

test_values[na_loc] = None
test_values_2[na_loc_2] = None
```

Comment: Accepted. Thank you very much!