# Get first non-null value per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe show as below.
For each line, I want to check the c1 first, if it is not null, then check c2. By this way, find the first notnull column and store that value to column result.

```
ID  c1  c2  c3  c4  result
1   a   b           a
2       cc  dd      cc
3           ee  ff  ee
4               gg  gg
```

I am using this way for now. but I would like to know if there is a better method.(The column name do not have any pattern, this is just sample)

```
df["result"] = np.where(df["c1"].notnull(), df["c1"], None)
df["result"] = np.where(df["result"].notnull(), df["result"], df["c2"])
df["result"] = np.where(df["result"].notnull(), df["result"], df["c3"])
df["result"] = np.where(df["result"].notnull(), df["result"], df["c4"])
df["result"] = np.where(df["result"].notnull(), df["result"], "unknown)
```

When there are lots of columns, this method looks not good.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309514/computing-the-first-non-missing-value-from-each-column-in-a-dataframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computing the first non-missing value from each column in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309514/computing-the-first-non-missing-value-from-each-column-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use back filling `NaN`s first and then select first column by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df['result'] = df[['c1','c2','c3','c4']].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].fillna('unknown')
```

Or:

```
df['result'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].fillna('unknown')
```

---

```
print (df)
   ID   c1   c2  c3   c4 result
0   1    a    b   a  NaN      a
1   2  NaN   cc  dd   cc     cc
2   3  NaN   ee  ff   ee     ee
3   4  NaN  NaN  gg   gg     gg
```

**Performance**:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)


In [220]: %timeit df['result'] = df[['c1','c2','c3','c4']].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].fillna('unknown')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.78 ms per loop

In [221]: %timeit df['result'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].fillna('unknown')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.7 ms per loop

#jpp solution
In [222]: %%timeit
     ...: cols = df.iloc[:, 1:].T.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index)
     ...: 
     ...: df['result'] = [df.loc[i, cols[i]] for i in range(len(df.index))]
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 180 ms per loop

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ'  s solution
In [223]: %timeit df['result'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).first()
1 loop, best of 3: 606 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**

```
df = df.set_index('ID') # if necessary
df
     c1   c2  c3   c4
ID                   
1     a    b   a  NaN
2   NaN   cc  dd   cc
3   NaN   ee  ff   ee
4   NaN  NaN  gg   gg
```

**Solution**
`stack` + `groupby` + `first`
`stack` implicitly drops NaNs, so `groupby.first` is guarantee to give you the first non-null value if it exists. Assigning the result back will expose any NaNs at missing indices which you can `fillna` with a subsequent call.

```
df['result'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).first()
# df['result'] = df['result'].fillna('unknown') # if necessary 
df
     c1   c2  c3   c4 result
ID                          
1     a    b   a  NaN      a
2   NaN   cc  dd   cc     cc
3   NaN   ee  ff   ee     ee
4   NaN  NaN  gg   gg     gg
```

(beware, this is slow for larger dataframes, for performance you may use @jezrael's solution)

Answer (score 2):

I am using `lookup` and data from Jpp

```
df=df.set_index('ID')
s=df.ne('').idxmax(1)
df['Result']=df.lookup(s.index,s)
df
Out[492]: 
   c1  c2  c3  c4 Result
ID                      
1   a   b              a
2      cc  dd         cc
3          ee  ff     ee
4              gg     gg
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [`pd.DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) with [`pd.Series.first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html) applied on a transposed dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'c1': ['a', '', '', ''],
                   'c2': ['b', 'cc', '', ''],
                   'c3': ['' , 'dd', 'ee', ''],
                   'c4': ['', '', 'ff', 'gg']})

df = df.replace('', np.nan)

df['result'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.iloc[:, 1:].T.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index))

print(df)

   ID   c1   c2   c3   c4 result
0   1    a    b  NaN  NaN      a
1   2  NaN   cc   dd  NaN     cc
2   3  NaN  NaN   ee   ff     ee
3   4  NaN  NaN  NaN   gg     gg
```