# df fill up values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df in python:

```
Course  |Student 1 | Student 2 | Student 3
--------|----------|-----------|---------
Course2 | 1.1      | empty     | empty
Course2 | empty    | 5.3       | empty
Course2 | empty    | empty     | 4.2
```

However, I want to have the following df:

```
Course  |Student 1 | Student 2 | Student 3
--------|----------|-----------|---------
Course2 | 1.1      | 5.3       | 4.2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what if there are multiple values for the same course?

Comment: @drum, there are not.

Comment: This should get your far enough for you to complete the rest https://stackoverflow.com/a/23309585/1061193

Comment: I assume you're using Pandas, so I added the [tag:pandas] tag for you. If that's incorrect, you can [edit] to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

As numbers evaluate before letters, you can groupby "Course" and take the min:

```
df.groupby('Course').agg('min')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have different datatypes(or in your current scenario also) in your real data then you can use `first()`:

```
# df = df.replace('empty', float('NaN'))
df = df.groupby('Course', as_index=False).first()
```

output:

```
    Course Student 1 Student 2 Student 3
0  Course2       1.1       5.3       4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with the following code:

```
df.replace('empty', None)
```

Comment: Fixed what, sorry?