# Get latest non NA value per column

Tags: python, dataframe, filter, nan

I have a timeseries stored in a dataframe and would like to extract the latest non NAN value per column and store it in a single-row dataframe.

So my datraframe looks as follows:

```
data={  'col1' : [np.nan,np.nan,3], 'col2' : [1,np.nan,np.nan],'col3' : [np.nan,3,np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=pd.bdate_range(start='01.01.2020',end='01.05.2020'))
```

And my desired output should be sth. like:

```
   col1  col2 col3
0     3     1    3
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Locate first and last non NaN values in a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403469/locate-first-and-last-non-nan-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Since I am relatively new to python, I might have searched for the wrong keywords.
However, my question has a reproducible example that should help clarify.
I don't need the position, but the value itself.

Answer (score 1):

Using a apply on a column level, filtering the non-null entries and extracting the last element of each filtered column delivers the result.

```
df.apply(lambda x: x[x.notnull()].values[-1])
```